# silent installation using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
I am trying to install software using powershell silent scripting. To install this software we need to have JRE installed on machine. For this first we need to check weather JRE installed or not, if not installed then it needs to be installed. What approach needs to be followed?

I have tried with the below of code.
$LASTEXITCODE = 0
$workdir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java"

If (!(Test-Path $workdir))
{ 
 $LASTEXITCODE = (Start-Process "D:\jre-6u26-windows-i586.exe" -ArgumentList "/s" -Wait -PassThru).Exitcode
}
If($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
{
 $DCBdir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Compart"
 If (!(Test-Path $DCBdir))
 {
 $Installer="D:\sw.exe"
 $responsefile="D:\Sresponse.varfile"
 $a=@("-q", "-varfile", "$responsefile")
 start-process $Installer -ArgumentList $a -wait
 }
}  
$chkdir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SWFolder"
if(Test-Path -eq $chkdir)
{
 [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Installation completed successfully')
}

When I run script its workingfine as it is checking the previous installation and performing installation if not found the installation. But here I am getting as issue with this code.
```

If Java installed alredy means it should start the other installation. but here in my case its stopping the complete installation. 
after installation completed, I need to display the message like " Installation completed". But here its not working. AnNy wrong in the above code..??

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a free code-generating service but rather a programmer Q&A site. If you are asking how to manage software, you are better off asking on superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

One package manager that I like to use is [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/javaruntime) which has an approved package for JRE, it looks like.  A quick check wmi will tell you whether or not java is installed:

`$x = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name like 'Java(TM)%'" | Select -Expand Version`

You could also use `Test-Path` pointed at registry keys you know exist for the package.  Once you verify that JRE is not on the machine, then you can call out to Chocolatey to install it.

Comment: Use the registry. Using Win32_Product is dangerous because it can trigger a consistency check of installed packages.

Comment: An "approved" package in Chocolatey doesn't mean the vendor approved it.

Comment: Good clarification @Bill_Stewart - I simply meant to imply that it's theoretically working, not necessarily maintained by the vendor.

Comment: SO JRE will be installed by using Chocolatey...??

Comment: $workdir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java"
 
If (!(Test-Path $workdir))
{ 
$a=(Start-Process -FilePath "jre-6u26-windows-i586.exe" -ArgumentList "/S" ).Exitcode
}
If($a.Exitcode = 0)
{
 $othersw = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Com"
 If (!(Test-Path $othersw))
 {
 ##install othersw...}
I am trying like this..Will it work..??

Comment: I'd try and use the registry path as the path you test.  `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion"` is one that I found, but it may depend on your version of JRE.  You could test this on your local machine before deploying.  If you have the .exe, that would simplify things, you'll just need to make sure that either all computers have the JRE handy locally or store it on a network share that everyone has access to.  I'd use the absolute path "x:\Files\jre.exe" rather than a relative path "jre.exe"